# Break out of chroot using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, chroot

Title says it all. What code can I use in a node-js program to break out of a chroot?

I'm using it for an input assistant program. The input assistant program runs inside of a chroot created by crouton on a Chromebook. However, I want the input assistant to be able to break out of the linux chroot, into the root directory of my chromebook, so that I can run "adb" commands to interact with the Android subsystem. (to click areas of the screen and such)

I've already found ways to do it in Python and C++, but not NodeJS.

Comment: Have you tried writing a native node module in c++ .

Comment: @Ankur No, but I found a way to do it using the "posix" node-module. (with a small modification)

Comment: Also, why the downvotes? This is a legitimate question for a real project: https://github.com/Venryx/InputAssistant

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found out how by mimicking the code of this Perl script here: http://pentestmonkey.net/blog/chroot-breakout-perl

The NodeJS version is as follows: (note that it does require root access)

```
var fs = require("fs");
var posix = require("posix"); // run "npm install --save posix" first

function EscapeCHRoot() {
    var dir = "./tempChRoot";

    // create subfolder to be our new root
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    }

    // change root to the subdirectory (letting us break out, ie. use "..")
    posix.chroot(dir);

    // change current-directory, all the way up to host's root
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        process.chdir("..");
    }

    // change root to host's root folder, completing break-out process
    posix.chroot(".");
}
```

However, the code above does require a change to the "posix" npm module before usage. This is because the "posix" module, by default, changes the working directory to the chroot directory whenever chroot is run (which prevents the chroot breakout from working). So we need to edit the code so it leaves out the change-directory call.

To do this, open "node_modules/posix/src/posix.cc", and comment out these lines

```
// proper order is to first chdir() and then chroot()
if (chdir(*dir_path)) {
    return Nan::ThrowError(Nan::ErrnoException(errno, "chroot: chdir: ", ""));
}
```

Then run "npm install" in its folder.

That should be it. Running the EscapeCHRoot() function should now correctly escape, allowing code afterward to access the host system's files.

Comment: Does this work? It doesn't seem to, but I'm not testing on ChromeOS. And if it does, isn't that a vulnerability in the OS?

Comment: Yes, it worked for me on ChromeOS (in Crouton; not known if it works for the official ChromeOS Linux that was created later). As for the chroot trick being a vulnerability, I think I remember reading it wasn't considered that, because chroots were never intended as a security feature (rather, as a containerization approach). (And for ChromeOS specifically, you have to enable developer mode to even create the Crouton instance in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

For other people searching on the topic, I also found out how to do chroot escaping in Python. In this case, we don't need to mess with any external files, as the Python interpreter provides the `os.fchdir()` command which lets you restore the "current directory" to the above-chroot folder after `os.chroot(".")` places it underneath.

```
import os

# store reference to original root, so we can return to it later
real_root = os.open("/", os.O_RDONLY)

# create subfolder to be our new root
if not os.path.exists("/tempChRoot"):
  os.makedirs("/tempChRoot")

# change root to the new subfolder
os.chroot("/tempChRoot")

# change current-directory back to original root
os.fchdir(real_root)

# change current-directory, all the way up to host's root
for i in range(100):
  os.chdir("..")

# change root to host's root folder, completing break-out process
os.chroot(".")
os.close(real_root)

# launch new (out of chroot) shell
os.system("bash") # alternative: "sh"
```

I currently use the NodeJS chroot-escaping for my input-assistant program, and this Python script as a helper when I have a shell open in crouton and I want to access files outside of its chroot.